# Почему не сохраняются картинки в heroku (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Здравствуйте, вопрос по сути уже задан. Добавляю изображение на сайт, через некоторое время захожу, а его уже нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku так устроен, что ваш сервер включается только когда к нему идут обращения. Если обращений к сайту нет, ваш инстанс выключается и вся сохраненная на нем в ходе работы информация обнуляется. При использовании Heroku лучше отправлять изображения в какое-нибудь долговременное облачное хранилище (Swift, S3). Тем более они почти все допускают привязку доменного имени, в результате чего вы сможете отдавать изображения с поддомена вашего сайта img.yoursite.com.

Comment: спасибо! Выходит, что например гем paperclip использовать нет смысла?

Comment: Почему же, вы же можете указать в has_attached_file тип хранилища storage. PaperClip довольно гибкий.